# Having trouble accessing value of a clicked param

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, reactjs

I am having trouble getting the value for my "selected" element from a click event.  I have posted the main piece of code below, which I think is causing the issue.  I will post the whole code further below.

Basically I want to click on an item in my first dropdown, and based on that clicked item, a second dropdown will be populated.  I think my issue is that in my onClick function, "selected: param.tableName" is grabbing nothing or something without the value I want possibly, because my second dropdown does not populate.

SUSPECTED PROBLEM CODE: (specifically "selected: param.tableName")

```
<select>{this.state.params.map((param, i) =>
                       <option key={i} onClick={() => {this.setState({selected: param.tableName})}}>{param.tableName}

                       </option>)}
                   </select>
```

REST OF CODE:

```
import React from 'react';
   import axios from 'axios';
   class Search extends React.Component {
       constructor(props) {
           super(props)
           this.state = {
               params: [],
               columnParams: [],
               selected: ''
           }
       }

       componentWillMount() {
           axios.get('http://localhost:3010/api/schema')
           .then( response => {
               this.setState({params: response.data})
           })
       }
       render() {
           return (
               <div className="Search">
                   <select>{this.state.params.map((param, i) =>
                       <option key={i} onClick={() => {this.setState({selected: param.tableName})}}>{param.tableName}

                       </option>)}
                   </select>
                   <select>{this.state.params
                           .filter(({tableName}) => tableName === this.state.selected)
                           .map(({columns}) =>
                               columns.map((col) =>
                       <option>{col}</option>))}
                   </select>
                   <input>
                   </input>
                   <select>
                   </select>
                   <button>
                   Go!
                   </button>
               </div>
               );
       }
   }
   export default Search
```

JSON:

```
   [
   {
   "tableName": "customer",
   "columns": [
   "customerid",
   "title",
   "prefix",
   "firstname",
   "lastname",
   "suffix",
   "phone",
   "email"
   ]
   },
   {
   "tableName": "product",
   "columns": [
   "productid",
   "name",
   "color",
   "price",
   "productadjective",
   "productmaterial"
   ]
   },
   {
   "tableName": "orderlineitem",
   "columns": [
   "orderid",
   "productid",
   "quantity"
   ]
   },
   {
   "tableName": "order",
   "columns": [
   "orderid",
   "customerid",
   "amount",
   "date"
   ]
   }
   ]
```

Comment: do AJAX calll (`axios`) inside   `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount `

Comment: Like this?
`componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:3010/api/schema')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({params:response.data})
        })
    }`